# Makefile ifeq fails

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefile and find using findstring rather hard.
Here's my code:

```
ZSHRC="$HOME/.zshrc"

install:
    ifneq($(findstring "CADANSE",$(ZSHRC) a),)
        @echo "done $(a)"
    endif
```

Wherever I move the comma I get errors, most frequently:

> syntax error near unexpected token `,'

I made sure my tabs are 4 proper spaces and tried a couple of tutorials to get it working but to no avail.

I need to check if the string BEGIN.CADANSE is in .zshrc because it loads extra shell methods. I'm trying to make an installer for it, makefile is not mandatory but I've been required to investigate it.

Thank you for any help.

OS is latest MacOSX and shell is oh-my-zsh.

## UPDATE - Solution

To address my issue I'm going through a patch now, instead of a grep:

```
installcadanse: docs
        @cat ~/.zshrc lib/Cadanse/template/dot-rc | diff -u ~/.zshrc - > PATCH_CADANSE ; patch ~/.zshrc PATCH_CADANSE
        @source ~/.zshrc ; echo "Cadanse should be installed in your shell. Please check ~/.zshrc for mentions of Cadanse."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeroth of all, what do you mean by "*my tabs are 4 proper spaces*"? The action part of a rule must be indented by a tab. Not 4 spaces, not 8 spaces, but a literal tab character.

First, the commands associated with a rule are passed to the shell (after variable expansion). If you want to test a condition in an action, you have to write a shell command for it, not a make command.

Second, `findstring` performs a simple substring search. It does not open any files or read their contents.

Third, I'm pretty sure `"$HOME/.zshrc"` in make means `"${H}OME/.zshrc"` (i.e. it'll look for a variable called `H`). Also, those quotes are taken literally.

To search a file for a given string in a shell script, you can use `grep`:

```
.PHONY: install

install:
        @if grep -q CADANSE ~/.zshrc; then \
            echo done; \
        fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a fourth editor helped me fix the indentation issue.
Couple of weeks later i'm more confortable with make and haven't tried yet a condition. I've changed my way to do it, instead of manually checking for a string I create a patch and apply it if necessary :), thought it was more elegant than any grep or findstring approach. I haven't checked the ${HOME} issue but sure will soon enough!
Thank you again,