# Variables cannot be compared in Makefile

Tags: makefile

i wrote following code.
but i faced the errors.

```
result=1
ifeq (,1)
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `,1'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `ifeq (,1)'
```

```
test:
     result=$(shell cat test_result | grep "Bad idea" | wc -l)
     ifeq ($(result),1)
          @echo "test passed"
     else
          @echo "test failed"
     endif
```

Why does this happen?
Can you tell me?

Comment: i saw gnu make documents.[link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example)
i wrote the code like code in documents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile ifeq fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617020/makefile-ifeq-fails)

Answer (score 1):

These conditionals need to be at the top-level and are evaluated when the make file is read, not when the target is executed. Further, you'll need something like `xargs` to strip the whitespace on the result. Then it works like you might expect.

```
result := $(shell cat test_result | grep "Bad idea" | wc -l | xargs)
ifeq ($(result),1)
    out := "test passed"
else
    out := "test failed"
endif

test:
    echo ${out}
```

This gives an exchange like:

```
➜ make
echo "test failed"
test failed

➜ echo "Bad idea" > test_result 

➜ make                         
echo "test passed"
test passed
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I didn't tell you.
sorry.
I wanted to test the output of the file after building it.

Comment: That isn't how make conditionals work. Maybe you can be more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish. It is possible to use further shell commands within the target, but that may not be helpful, depending on your actual goal.

Comment: `cat test_result | grep "Bad idea" | wc -l | xargs` is uselessly complicated. There is no need to "_strip the whitespace_". Moreover `cat | grep` is a common anti-pattern. `grep -c "Bad idea" test_result` is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet 100% agree. I simply added it to make the rest of the pre-existing statement work, convoluted as it is. But you do need to strip whitespace from the output of `wc -l` if you want to match it to `1` here.

Comment: I realize that my comment was not 100% clear: yes, stripping the white spaces is needed if you use `wc -l` but not with `grep -c`.